# How can I change the whole schema of mongodb with existing data?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to change database mysql to mongodb,
Wanting to change whole data schema.

And I succeed to migrate data.

But I want to change this mongodb documents schema from

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581c45b1a5245ca984000009"),
    "memb_id" : "ME20160520041223736026",
    "story_category_id" : "S001000",
    "story_pet_category" : "D",
    "temp_text" : "THIS IS DATA TO CHANGE",
    "story_status" : "D",
    "regtime" : 1463988822,
    "modifytime" : 1468573528,
    "story_contents" : [ 
        {
            "story_image_url" : "/uploads/2016/05/23/compression/728870e82c47901a70509cfdc2bc3b56.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "story_image_url" : "/uploads/2016/05/23/compression/fd1552e1ea5380fc0cdae793336a8d67.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "story_image_url" : "/uploads/2016/05/23/compression/2aaff6a75db4c8bfa1a0133234d3e6fe.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

to

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581c45b1a5245ca984000009"),
    "memb_id" : "ME20160520041223736026",
    "story_category_id" : "S001000",
    "story_pet_category" : "D",
    "story_status" : "D",
    "regtime" : 1463988822,
    "modifytime" : 1468573528,
    "story_contents" : [
        {
            "story_text":"THIS IS DATA TO CHANGE",
            "story_image_url":""
        }
        {
            "story_text":"",
            "story_image_url" : "/uploads/2016/05/23/compression/728870e82c47901a70509cfdc2bc3b56.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "story_text":"",
            "story_image_url" : "/uploads/2016/05/23/compression/fd1552e1ea5380fc0cdae793336a8d67.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "story_text":"",
            "story_image_url" : "/uploads/2016/05/23/compression/2aaff6a75db4c8bfa1a0133234d3e6fe.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Exactly what I want is Pushing that "temp_text" in "story_contents" Array, Changing "story_contents"'s schema like this. (Whole 6423 documents)

How can I write mongodb query..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with an [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/) that will add `story_text` field/value to all items from `story_contents` array :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$story_contents"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        memb_id: { $first: "$memb_id" },
        story_category_id: { $first: "$story_category_id" },
        story_pet_category: { $first: "$story_pet_category" },
        story_status: { $first: "$story_status" },
        regtime: { $first: "$regtime" },
        modifytime: { $first: "$modifytime" },
        story_contents: {
            $push: { temp_text: "$temp_text", story_image_url: "$story_contents.story_image_url" }
        }
    }
}, {
    $out: "collection2"
}])
```

- 1 `$unwind` to convert `story_contents` array to JSON object
- 1 `$group` to regroup all the items by `_id` with construction of the new array `story_contents` with additional `temp_text` field
- 1 `$out` to write the result into a new collection named `collection2`